# Problems to input data to Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm importing some data from Excel to a database. I have a lot of spreadsheets but some of them have problems when I try to input with Microsoft Excel Input. Actually I've tried to use the CSV File Input and the problem was the same.

I have this spreadsheet:
[Data in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHSTC.png)

Preview data in Pentaho:
[Data in Pentaho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctlwQ.png)

As you can see, data from some columns changed. For example, data from `camada_nome` went to `profund_inf`

Why is this happening? And why does it only happen with some spreadsheets? It's possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you select only some fields of the original sheet on the  "Fields" tab of Microsoft Excel Input step?

I can see in the preview that the input has less fields than the original spreadsheet. When you select fields in that way, kettle "moves" fields.

If you need only a subset of all fields, first you must import all of them with Microsoft Excel Input step, and in a second step select the desired fields with a "Select" step.

Comment: Hi! I'm importing all of them and selecting with a "Select" step. I put the image that way to reduce its size.
Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Sabrina, I could not replicate the problem exactly as you report, after a select step. Which version of Kettle are you using? Is it possible to upload the  ktr file and a sample of xlsx file?

Comment: I was deleting some fields in Microsoft Excel Input step and that was generating the problem. It's working now! Thanks, you help me a lot!!